# How to insert data into one table row from multiple table rows in another table in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and I want to populate table 2 as a single row with data from table 1 -> New_Value (in different rows)

Table 1:

```
Id   Old_Value    New_Value
----------------------------
1     xyz         abc
2     123         456
3     A123        J345
```

Table 2:

```
Key  Value1 Value2 Value3
--------------------------
1    abc     456    J435
```

Comment: did you try anyhting?

Comment: Is that only one column new_Value that you want to insert as row?

Comment: @Manish..I tried the simple insert into () select..but that did not work. it populates data into multiple rows.

Comment: @DarkKnight - Yes, i want to insert only one column value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *
from (select id,new_value from @abc) s
pivot
(
  max(new_value)
  for id in ([1],[2],[3])
) u
```

Comment: Thank You. I will try this out.